# (Python) Solving Tolman Oppenheimer Volkoff equations

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, astrophysics, computational-physics, software

I'm trying to obtain the Mass-radius diagram of a non-rotating neutron star, following the work of [Oppenheimer and Volkoff](https://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/homes/fendt/Lehre/Vorlesung_CO/1939_oppenheimer_volkoff.pdf) (I consider an EoS of a free Fermi gas of neutrons) :

$$E(x)=\epsilon_0\left[(2x^3+x)(1+x^2)^{1/2}-\text{arcsinh}(x)\right]=\epsilon_0 e(x) $$
$$P(x)=\epsilon_0\left[\left(\frac{2}{3}x^3-x\right)\left(1+x^2\right)^{1/2} +\text{arcsinh}(x) \right]=\epsilon_0 p(x)$$
$$\text{where : } \epsilon_0=\frac{\hbar c}{8\pi^2\lambda_{c,n}}=\frac{\hbar c}{8\pi^2}\left(\frac{m_n c}{\hbar}\right)^4$$

In the following code, I work using dimensionless EoS (where eos_E(x) is e(x) defined by $e(x)=E(x)/\epsilon_0$ and eos_P(x,0) is p(x) defined by $p(x)=P(x)/\epsilon_0$) and the (dimensionless) ToV equations of [J.Piekarewicz](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-319-21846-5_54) :

$$ \frac{dm}{d\bar r}=3\bar r^2 e(\bar{r}) \qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad\qquad \frac{dp}{d\bar r}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(e(\bar{r})+p(\bar{r})\right)\left(m(\bar{r})+3\bar{r}^3 p(\bar{r})\right)}{\bar{r}^2 \left(1-m(\bar{r})/\bar{r}\right)}$$

Where the mass $M$, the radius $r$ and the pressure $P$ are simply given by : 
$$M=M_0 m \qquad\text{,}\qquad r=R_0 \bar{r} \qquad \text{and} \qquad P=\epsilon_0 p$$
where
$$  R_0 = \sqrt{\frac{3\pi \hbar c}{G m_n^2}}\left(\frac{\hbar}{m_n c}\right)\simeq 8378\; m \qquad\qquad M_0=\frac{R_0 c^2}{2G}\simeq 5.643*10^{30}\, kg   $$

These equations are integrated from the center (where $\bar{r}=\bar{r}_c=0.0012$) up to ($\bar{r}=2.4$) using a 4th order Runge-Kutta integrator and the Mewton's method (For each value of $p$, I solve $p(x_p)=p$ before injecting the $x_p$ value in $e(x)$), for each initial condition : 
$$p(\bar{r}_c)=p_c \qquad\qquad m(\bar{r}_c)=e(x_c)\bar{r}_c \qquad\qquad\text{where}\qquad p(x_c)=p_c $$

where the dimensionless central-pressure runs from $p_c=10^{-1.5}$ up to $p_c=10^{3.5}$.

My code is the following :

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
import odeint
from scipy.optimize import newton
from scipy.constants import pi, G, c, hbar, m_n, m_p, m_e

"____________________________FUNDAMENTAL CONSTANTS____________________________"

M_Sun = 1.98892e30 # Solar mass (kg)
Rs_Sun = (2.0*G*M_Sun)/c**2.0 # Schwartzschild radius of Sun (m)
Compton_n = hbar/(m_n*c) # Neutronic Compton Wavelength (m)
alpha_G = (G*m_n**2.0)/(hbar*c) # Gravitational coupling constant for neutron

"___________________________NORMALIZATION CONSTANTS___________________________"

Epsilon_0 = hbar*c/(8.0*Compton_n**4.0 * pi**2.0) # Energy/Pressure unity (J/m³)
R_0 = np.sqrt(3.0*pi/alpha_G)*Compton_n # Radius unity (m)
M_0 = R_0*M_Sun/Rs_Sun # Mass unity (kg)

"_______________________________RK4 INTEGRATOR________________________________"

# Fourth order Runge-Kutta integration step.
def rk4(f,y,x,h):
    k1=f(y,x)*h
    k2=f(y+0.5*k1,x+0.5*h)*h
    k3=f(y+0.5*k2,x+0.5*h)*h
    k4=f(y+k3,x+h)*h
    return y + k1/6.0 + k2/3.0 + k3/3.0 + k4/6.0 

"______________________________DIMENSIONLESS EoS______________________________"

# Dimensionless Energy density in terms of x=Compton_n*neutron Fermi wavevector
def eos_E(x): # eos_E(x)=E(x)/Epsilon_0
    return (2.0*x**3.0 + x)*(1.0 + x**2.0)**(1.0/2.0) - np.arcsinh(x)

# eox_P(x,O) = Dimensionless Pressure in terms of x = Compton_n*neutron Fermi 
#              wavevector 
def eos_P(x,P): #eos_P(x,0)=P(x)/Epsilon_0
    return ((2.0*x**3.0)/3.0 - x)*(1.0 + x**2.0)**(1.0/2.0) + np.arcsinh(x) - P

"______________________eos_P INVERSION (NEWTON'S METHOD)______________________"

# Derivative deos_P(x)/dx used for Newton's method.            
def deos_P(x,P):
    return (8.0*x**4.0)/(3.0*(1+x**2.0)**(1.0/2.0))

# Solving the equation eos_P(x,0) = P <=> eos_P(x,P) = 0 using Newton's method
def x_finder(P):
    return newton(eos_P,1.0,fprime=deos_P,args=(P, ),maxiter=1000)

"_________________________DIMENSIONLESS ToV EQUATIONS_________________________"

###############################################################################
##### Definition of (Dimensionless) Tolman Oppenheimer Volkoff equations ######
###############################################################################
# The system is given by : dmdr = 3.0*E_Norm*r**2.0                           #
#                 and -(E_Norm + p)*(m + 3.0*p*r**3.0)/(2.0*(1.0-m/r)*r**2.0) #
#     The unknowns are : m, p and E_Norm. For each p, we solve the equation   # 
#                        eos_P(x_p)=p (using Newton's method which gives x_p  #
#                        which gives the value of E_Norm=eos_E(x_p) and       #
#                        completes the system.                                #
###############################################################################                       
def ToV(y,r):
    p,m = y[0],y[1]
    #x_p = x_finder(p)
    #E_Norm = eos_E(x_p)
    E_Norm = eos_E(x_finder(p))
    dpdr = -(E_Norm + p)*(m + 3.0*p*r**3.0)/(2.0*(1.0-m/r)*r**2.0)
    dmdr = 3.0*E_Norm*r**2.0
    return pylab.array([dpdr,dmdr])

def ToVSolve(pc,x_c):
    # Initialization of m(r), p(r) and r (dimensionless)
    dr=0.0024 
    r = pylab.arange(0.0012,2.4,dr) #1.2e-3,2.4,dr
    m, p = pylab.zeros_like(r), pylab.zeros_like(r)
    m[0] = eos_E(x_c)*r[0]**3.0
    p[0] = pc
    y=pylab.array([p[0],m[0]])
    i=0
    while p[i]>0.0 and i<len(r)-1:
        #dr=r[i+1]-r[i]
        y=odeint.rk4(ToV,y,r[i],dr)
        p[i+1] = y[0]
        m[i+1] = y[1]
        i=i+1
    # Return the Mass (in solar masses) and the Radius (in km) of the NS
    return m[i-1]*M_0/M_Sun, r[i-1]*R_0/1000.0 

"______________________________Mass-Radius plot______________________________ "


pc = pylab.logspace(-1.5,3.5)
xc = pylab.zeros_like(pc)
M = pylab.zeros_like(pc)
R = pylab.zeros_like(pc)

for i in range(len(pc)):
    xc[i]=x_finder(pc[i])
    M[i],R[i] = ToVSolve(pc[i],xc[i])
    print("Step : "+str(i))

print("The total mass of a NS is : M_max = "+str(M.max())+\
      " M_Sun")
pylab.plot(R,M)
pylab.xlabel('Radius (km)')
pylab.ylabel('Mass (solar)')
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()
```

The problem I have is, when I compute this code, I found the right value of the Neutron Star masses (in particular, the maximal mass $M_{NS}^{Max}=0.71\; M_{\odot}$ for $P_c=3.5*10^{35}\; dyne/cm^2$ as it was obtained by Oppenheimer and Volkoff) but I can't find the Mass-Radius diagram since the radius I obtain is frozen at R=20.077 km for every mass value...

Since yesturday, I've tried to find where the problem might but I still don't know where it is, so I post it here in the hope someone will find it ; thank you in advance ! ;)

Comment: Is there a typo in what you write above - in your programme you use $m(x_c) = e(x_c) r_c^3$?  Your pressure never drops below zero, so you never reach the surface of the neutron star. Unfortunately, the reference you cite is behind a paywall.

Comment: I'm quite interested in getting this working now and am equally puzzled. Could you send me a copy of the cited paper so I could look through the equations. I can't figure out why the pressure isn't dropping to zero. Follow my profile for contact info.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not about physical concepts but computational issues.

Comment: @ohneVal - I agree, note to OP there is a dedicated [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) specific for these kinds of computational issues

Answer (score 0):

This is more a computational question than a physics one, and the only reason I'm writing this as an answer is because it's a bit too long for a comment: to me your problem seems to be in the `ToVSolve` function.

```
def ToVSolve(pc,x_c):
# Initialization of m(r), p(r) and r (dimensionless)
dr=0.0024 
r = pylab.arange(0.0012,2.4,dr) #1.2e-3,2.4,dr
m, p = pylab.zeros_like(r), pylab.zeros_like(r)
m[0] = eos_E(x_c)*r[0]**3.0
p[0] = pc
y=pylab.array([p[0],m[0]])
i=0
while p[i]>0.0 and i<len(r)-1:
    #dr=r[i+1]-r[i]
    y=odeint.rk4(ToV,y,r[i],dr)
    p[i+1] = y[0]
    m[i+1] = y[1]
    i=i+1
# Return the Mass (in solar masses) and the Radius (in km) of the NS
return m[i-1]*M_0/M_Sun, r[i-1]*R_0/1000.0
```

At the end, you ask the function to essentially return `m[i-1]` and `r[i-1]` (times some constants). Now, the index `i` currently has a value of `len(r)-1` (since you've just run a loop that increments its value up to that), and so your function will always return `m[len(r)-2]` and `r[len(r)-2]`. Now, the values of `m` are updated in the loop, but you never update the values of `r`! And so you will always get the same (initial) value of `r[len(r)-2] = 2.3964`, which results in your `R` array always having the same value of `r[len(r)-2]*R_0/1000 = 20.07723386`.

I haven't read through the theory sufficiently well to be sure that there aren't any other errors, but this would clearly explain why the `R` array's value is always the same!

Comment: The point of the loop is to stop when the pressure drops below zero and the surface of the star is reached. It should not be reaching the end of the radius array unless there is a problem somewhere else (or the radius of the neutron star is bigger than 20.07 km).

Comment: @RobJeffries Thanks! Should've seen the `p[i]>0.0` there. So essentially the problem with the code is that it's reaching the end of the radius array? I actually don't know too much about it, I should probably not have answered. Thanks for letting me know!